# Styles in MatSnackBar open from component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm looking for a way to do the following: to show notifications, I want to implement a custom SnackBar. I followed the official doc ([here](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)) and I created a simple Snackbar, with some custom configuration.

```
this.snackBar.open('Message one', 'OK', configSuccess);

export const configSuccess: MatSnackBarConfig = {
  panelClass: 'style-success',
  duration: 10000,
  horizontalPosition: 'left',
  verticalPosition: 'bottom'
};
```

This works fine, but I want a different display in my SnackBar (specifically send data and display two buttons). Following the docs, I create a component and open my SnackBar from it :

```
/*...*/    
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMessageComponent, {
              data: 'Message one',
            });
/*...*/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snackbar-message',
  templateUrl: './snackbar-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snackbar-message.component.scss']
})
export class SnackbarMessageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

All ok, but now I have a problem. I want to pass to this new SnackBar the config that I defined before (`config Success` for example), but in the official docs and Google I didn't find anything.

Is there any way to do it without having to define it globally? Can someone guide me or tell me where to go? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, thanks to [shivensinha4](https://github.com/shivensinha4) in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13300), I have the key :

It can provide the styles as well to the `openFromComponent` function, like this:

```
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMessageComponent, {
  data: 'Message one',
  ...this.configSuccess
});
```

Here's the working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2nc51?file=app/snack-bar-component-example.ts)